# Perl Regex Replace Double Quotes With Single Quotes

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a long string which looks like this:

```
"Key1:Value1,
 Key2:value2,
 Key3:namespace="randomName",
 Key4:Some other value,
 Key5:namespace="anotherRandomName"
...
"
```

I want to replace `namespace="randomName"` with `namespace='randomName'` (just from double quotes to single quotes).

What's the best way to do it with perl regex?

Comment: `s/(:namespace=)"([^"]*)"/$1'$2'/`

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service (although I see that two people have already decided to be generous and write code for you!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<EOD;
Key1:Value1,
Key2:value2,
Key3:namespace="randomName",
Key4:Some other value,
Key5:namespace="anotherRandomName"
EOD
$str =~  s/\bnamespace=\K"([^"]+)"/'$1'/g;

print $str;
```

**Output:**

```
Key1:Value1,
Key2:value2,
Key3:namespace='randomName',
Key4:Some other value,
Key5:namespace='anotherRandomName'
```